# Fallback to the "default browser behavior" on an URL instead of interpreting it as a SvelteKit route

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a route on the path `/src/routes/[first]/[[second]]/+page.ts`.

So far so good.

But! Now I also have static assets such as `/static/attachments/image1.jpg`.  These assets are unreachable because the `[first]/[[second]]` route gets in the way.

To clarify, if I write an anchor tag such as `<a href="/attachments/image1.jpg">Download the picture</a>`, clicking this link will lead the visitor's browser to try to run the `[first]/[[second]]` route, not just download the asset.

Sidenote: oddly enough, it works fine with `img` tags, i.e.
`<img src="/attachments/image1.jpg"></img>` will render an image as intended.  So the path exists.  I just need to make the SvelteKit router understand that for the `a` tag too.

**Question: is there something like a way to "throw redirect()" to treat an URL as just an asset?**

PS: yes I know about the possibility of `import` via Javascript, which would be ideal, but it's not an option since my anchor tags come from inside a `{@html post.content}` expression. So I must use static asset paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `rel="external"` attribute to your link tag. Please see the SvelteKit documentation about [Link options](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options) for details about this. A `data-sveltekit-reload` might not what you are looking for as you try to link an asset and want to prevent a svelte route to be linked.